# How to connecting swift to coreML (in swift playground)?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, coreml

I trying to connecting swiftUI to CoreML (in Swift Playground) and here is the code;

```
import CoreML
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
@State private var wakeUp = Date.now
@State private var sleepAmount = 8.0
@State private var coffeAmount = 1
@State private var alertTitle = ""
@State private var alertMessage = ""
@State private var showingAlert = false


 Let model = SleepCalculator()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            Text("when do u want to wake up")
                .font(.headline)
            
            DatePicker("please enter a time", selection:         $wakeUp, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                .labelsHidden()
            
            Text("desired amount of sleep")
                .font(.headline)
            
            Stepper("\(sleepAmount.formatted()) hours", value: $sleepAmount, in: 4...12,step: 0.25)
            
            Text("daily coffe intake")
                .font(.headline)
            
            Stepper(coffeAmount == 1 ? "1 cup" : "\(coffeAmount) cups", value: $coffeAmount, in: 1...20)
            
                .alert(alertTitle, isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                    Button("ok") { }
                } message: {
                    Text(alertMessage)
                }
        }
        .navigationTitle("betterRest")
        .toolbar {
            Button("calculate", action: calculateBedtime)
        }
        .alert(alertTitle, isPresented: $showingAlert) {
            Button("ok") { }
        } message: {
            Text(alertMessage)
        }
    }
}
 
func calculateBedtime() {
    do {
        
        let config = MLModelConfiguration()
        
        let model = try SleepCalculator(configuration: config)
        
        let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: wakeUp)
        let hour = (components.hour ?? 0) * 60 * 60
        let minute = (components.minute ?? 0) * 60 * 60
        
        let predication = try model.predication(wake: Double(hour + minute), estimatedSleep: sleepAmount, coffe: Double(coffeAmount))
        
        let sleepTime = wakeUp - predication.actualSleep
        alertTitle = "Your ideal bedtime is…"
        
        alertMessage = sleepTime
        
    } catch {
        alertTitle = "error"
        alertMessage = "sorry, there was a problem  calculating your bedtime."
    }
    showingAlert = true
    }
   }
      struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
      ContentView()
   }
  }
```

> Error 1 -cannot find ‘SleepCalculator’ in scope.

Problem in this line:

```
let model = try SleepCalculator(configuration: config)
```

And;

```
Let mode = sleepcalculator()
```

says it wrong i don’t know why ?

How to fix it?
I don't understand what is the function of SleepCalculator here. And how to fix the error ? Thanks.

Comment: What's `SleepCalculator`? Is it a custom class of yours?

Comment: SleepCalculator seems to be the CoreML model. Whatever tutorial you are following should address where to get the model from. Then you add it to the project.

Comment: Still didn’t get it

Comment: You are missing a file, `SleepCalculator` is a file.

Comment: You are right but there is no other addition about sleepcalculator in the tutorial I followed, I just found it designed that way,thank you

Comment: I don't know what tutorial you are following but I am willing to bet that there is a "pre tutorial" that you are missing. Something with the topic of Create ML where they likely create the model.

Comment: The tutorial i am following is ‘100 day with swiftUI’ day 27-28.

Comment: Look at day 26, that tutorial seems pretty detailed from what I have heard. I am sure it is a matter of you skipping a lesson.

Comment: -Dávid Pásztor
yes it’s custom class,u have an idea?

Comment: Let me tell you coreML is just use to use created ML Model in your Application. You first need to create model for that you can use CreateML. and then bind that model in your app with help of coreML.